# query scope is not working, it is not showing filtered data in laravel 8.77 project

Tags: laravel, eloquent

query scope is not working, i'm doing `dd()` but can't solve the issue this way

**queryscope method in model**

```php
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    {
        $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, fn($query, $search) => $query
            ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        );

        $query->when($filters['category'] ?? false, fn($query, $category) => $query
            ->whereExists(fn($query) => $query
                ->from('categories')
                ->whereColumn('categories.id', 'posts.category_id')
                ->where('category.slug', $category)
            )
        );
    }
```

**index (show all posts with filter) method in controller**

```php
public function index()
    {
        return view('posts', [
            'posts' => Post::latest()->filter(request(['search', 'category']))->get(),
            'categories' => Category::all()
        ]);
    }
```

when i do like this `127.0.0.1:8000/?categories=nihil-est-odit-nam-provident-omnis`, it has to work and filter the posts with categories with given slug, but it is showing all the posts, even in the `clockwork` browser extension, it also showing the `categories' => Category::all()` line, and this is executed, not the actual filtered query

Comment: @Garry, should i write ```return``` two times?

Comment: You need only one return, at the end of `scopeFilter`, to return the query builder.

Comment: @Alex `Scopes should always return the same query builder instance or void` this is from documentation, `return` isn't necessary.

Comment: @SiZE I stand corrected, you're right.

Comment: ```$query->when($filters['category'] ?? false, fn($query, $category) => $query
            ->whereHas('category', fn($query) => $query->where('slug', $category)));```
i did this, but still not working, what might be the issue in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    $search = $filters['search'] ?? false;
    $category = $filters['category'] ?? false;

    $query
        ->when($search, function ($query, $search) {
            $query
                ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
        ->when($category, function ($query, $category) {
            $query
                ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                    $query->where('slug', $category);
                });
       });
 }
```

Assuming you have a `categories()` relationship defined in Post Model, I believe this should work for you.

Also `dd(request(['search', 'category']))` to check if you are getting the array you want.